# How do I create a vector that accepts strings?

Tags: matlab

Ok the problem is, I want to receive mathematical functions. And I won't know how many until the program runs.

When it runs i ask for an `n` number of functions i am going to receive and it starts saving them from the input.

So far I have this

```
function test()  
n = input('number of equations?');  
v = [1:n]  
%in an ideal world, this ^ here would allow me to put a string in each position but  
% they are not the same type and I understand that.. but how can I build a vector for saving my                functions  
%I want a vector where I can put strings in each position that is what I need   
for i=1:n  
x = input('what is the function?','s');  
v(i)=x  
end  
v   
%this would be my vector already changed with a function in each position.  
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to store strings of different lengths, use cell arrays:

```
v = cell(1,n);
for i=1:n   
    v{i} = input('what is the function?','s'); #% note the curly braces
end
```

To use these as functions, use [str2func](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html):

```
for i=1:n
    fh{i} = str2func(v{i});
end
```

`fh` is now a cell array containing handles to the functions defined by the user-input strings.